# take all rows by multiple conditions one to another column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a xls like below and i have a column name ID with value `1,2,3` i need to extract the data if `Name and Subname`  columns values are identical and having `1,2,3` these all should done by pandas

```
Name subname ID
 A      B      1
 A      B      2
 A      B      3
 A      C      1
 A      C      2
 F      C      1
 F      C      2
 F      C      3
```

expected output

```
Name subname 
 A      B      
 F      C
```

Comment: `These all should done by pandas`  so what have you tried?

Comment: i have tried spliting that using using  1,2,3 and camare that and taken .but i need that in simple code

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: because that is not working properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try creating uniques as a tuple for each group and compare, then return as dataframe:

```
uniques = df.groupby(['Name','subname'])['ID'].unique().map(tuple)
out = uniques.index[uniques==(1,2,3)].to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
print(out)

  Name subname
0    A       B
1    F       C
```